# Should we mass-redirect links to the Bash-Hackers' Wiki?

Tags: support, broken-link

One of the major historical references for information on bash (and more broadly, POSIX-family shells) went down some time ago.

Formerly, this was https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/, which is now dead. Here is a [list of SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Url%3Awiki.bash-hackers.org) containing that domain.

There are a few mirrors that have been created today; one of these is at https://flokoe.github.io/bash-hackers-wiki/

Is this a situation where it would be appropriate to use moderator/staff-only tools to mass-update links to point to the new reference?

Comment: *a few mirrors that have been created today* Might it be useful to wait some time to see which of those mirrors continue to exist or end up being the the best fixed up, since (according to that linked page) it looks like transferring everything over correctly requires some more work?

Comment: at least for [the top posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%22wiki.bash-hackers.org%22&searchOn=3) linking there, you could go manually finding archived versions of the page such as on web.archive.org. it would be manual work, but it would be high impact and perhaps less controversial in the short term than deciding on what mirror to use.

Comment: Most of the links on the front page of flokoe's mirror are broken because they're missing the `/bash-hackers-wiki/` prefix.

Comment: Perhaps a safer choice might be the Internet Archive?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think the hard part is finding the last saved version that isn't a save of a dead page, and perhaps cross-checking with other mirrors to see what the differences are (i.e. manual work is probably needed). but as I stated above, I agree that it's probably a less controversial choice.

Comment: The very least controversial choice is to not mass-edit anything, but rather update links as you naturally find them. Let's face facts here: links should not be important, they should be convenient. So it's annoying that the link is broken, but it's not hurting anyone either. Google, Bing and Duck Duck Go still work.